compile files failed when .h and .cpp in different folders
I am a beginner in C++. I have my header files and source files stored in different folders as shown below. When I try to compile, I am unable to compile successfully.
test
├── inc
│   └── A.h
├── src
│   └── A.cpp
└── test.cpp

test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "inc\\A.h"
int main() {
    std::cout << A();
    return 0;
}

A.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

int A();
#endif

A.cpp
#include "..\\inc\\A.h"

int A() {
    return 1;
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(CPPproject)
SET(MAIN test.cpp)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

SET(Home "D:\\study\\test")
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${Home})
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc")
file(GLOB MAIN_SRC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB MAIN_HEAD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/*.h")

add_executable(test ${MAIN})

errors:
[build] CMakeFiles\test.dir/objects.a(test.cpp.obj): In function `main':
[build] D:/study/test/test.cpp:4: undefined reference to `A()'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I made some changes and replaced #include "inc\\A.h" in the main file with #include "src\\A.cpp", and the compilation was successful. However, I don't understand the reason behind it. This approach doesn't seem normal.

With add_executable(test ${MAIN}) you only add test.cpp to be built. You need to add all source files to your add_executable command.

Also note that including a source file with #include is in 99.999% of all cases wrong. With #include "src/A.cpp" you basically copy-paste the full contents of the A.cpp source file into test.cpp.

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status -- This is a linker error, not a compile error, thus it has absolutely nothing to do with the header files not being found.

note that it's not recommended to use GLOB

As an aside, the file names in #include are formally not string literals, so don't need escaped backslash characters. And you can use forward slashes / anyway, even on WIndows.

I think the code in this question has changed so that A is now a template. In C++ templates should be implemented in header files. I've added a duplicate answer that explains why.

Please do not change the question after it already has an answer.

You aren't currently including A.cpp in your compilation which the linker needs to resolve the A() function.
Your CMakeLists.txt file should look like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(CPPproject)
SET(MAIN test.cpp)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

SET(Home "D:\\study\\test")
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${Home})
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc")
file(GLOB MAIN_SRC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB MAIN_HEAD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/*.h")

add_executable(test ${MAIN} ${MAIN_SRC})

This would actually include your source file called A.cpp into your compilation.
Why it works when you are including the A.cpp file into your tests.cpp file is that the actual function definition ends up in your test.cpp file and the A() function is the compiled along with the rest of your code in the test.cpp file.

Globbing source and header files is generally a bad idea. Cmake recommends against it. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem

Yeah I agree, although I think that globbing source files would generally be a nice and fast solution for when coming up to speed in a project. Besides, it is a bit out of scope of this question.

Thank you for your help. Could you take a look at the issue after my modifications? I think I've not fully resolved it yet.

See the comment from john on your question above, you can't create a templated function in a source file, this needs to be included in a header file.
